# Express-validator bail() function conflicts with jest bail() function

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, express-validator

I am trying to use express-validator's bail function to return a validation chain instance when a previous validation has failed. However, the bail function is being identified as the bail function belonging to @jest/types. See picture below:

[image: IDE description of bail function]

When I try to run my code, I get the following error:

```
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" C:\dev\Home-Together-Canada\server\bin\www
C:\dev\Home-Together-Canada\server\controllers\validators\userControllerValidator.js:68
        .exists().bail()
                  ^

TypeError: body(...).exists(...).bail is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\dev\Home-Together-Canada\server\controllers\validators\userControllerValidator.js:68:19)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1083:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1112:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:948:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:789:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\dev\Home-Together-Canada\server\routes\businessRoutes.js:17:24)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1083:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1112:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:948:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:789:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\dev\Home-Together-Canada\server\app.js:11:24)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1083:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1112:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:948:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:789:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\dev\Home-Together-Canada\server\bin\www:7:11)
```

I have the following in my packagae.json file:

```
{
  "name": "home-together-canada",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server/bin/www",
    "test": "jest",
    "dev": "concurrently \"set PORT=3001 && npm start\" \" cd client && npm start\"",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install && npm run build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@turf/boolean-overlap": "^6.3.0",
    "@turf/boolean-point-in-polygon": "^6.3.0",
    "@turf/boolean-within": "^6.3.0",
    "@turf/circle": "^6.3.0",
    "@turf/helpers": "^6.3.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "express": "~4.16.1",
    "express-session": "^1.17.1",
    "express-validator": "^5.3.1",
    "hbs": "^4.1.1",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.3",
    "jest": "^26.6.0",
    "json2csv": "^5.0.6",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "morgan": "~1.9.1",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "mysql2": "^2.2.5",
    "neat-csv": "^6.0.1",
    "node-geocoder": "^3.27.0",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "sequelize": "^6.3.5"
  },
  "jest": {
    "verbose": true,
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.{js,jsx}",
      "!**/node_modules/**",
      "!**/*.test.js",
      "!**/coverage/**",
      "!**/serviceWorker.js",
      "!**/index.js"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/client/src/setupTests.js"
    ],
    "projects": [
      {
        "displayName": "server",
        "testEnvironment": "node",
        "testMatch": [
          "<rootDir>/server/**/*.test.js"
        ]
      },
      {
        "displayName": "client",
        "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
        "testMatch": [
          "<rootDir>/client/**/*.test.js"
        ],
        "moduleFileExtensions": [
          "js",
          "json",
          "jsx"
        ],
        "moduleNameMapper": {
          "\\.(css|less)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
        },
        "transform": {
          "\\.(js|jsx)$": "babel-jest",
          "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileTransformer.js"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.5",
    "concurrently": "^5.3.0",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

**How do I direct express-validator to use its own bail function instead of jest's?**